# Different variations of the chapters in table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, typography

How can I have my chapters in my thesis listed as "I-x", "II-y", "III-z" etc? At the moment its "1-x", "2-y", "3-z".

At the moment i'm using:

```
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
```

Also the document class is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}`?

Comment: @campa They look much better than the standard numbering system but all my theorems, lemmas etc will need to be adjusted, I'm too lazy! Is there a way to write "Chapter 1-x" in the TOC?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are after. In the question you claim to have 1-x and you want I-x, and in the comment you want now 1-x, which is what you allegedly already have. Please make your question more clear.

Comment: You answered the initial question which is why I didn't edit the original question. I would like the word "CHAPTER" to appear in the TOC. If you think it is unnecessary or doesn't look "good" then no worries!

Comment: Alternatively, is it possible to have the standard numbering system throughout the thesis but having "I, II,III" for the chapters only?